# Uniqify Django models with a unique attribute instead of using PK

Tags: python, django

In the Django docs it was stated that besides the Primary Key, if another attribute has the setting "unique" set to True, an IntegrityError would be thrown if a model with the same attribute was being added to the database (much like how the PK is handled).

However, even after setting the unique = True to one of my fields, no IntegrityErrors are thrown, and in the manage.py shell, i'm blatantly saving models with identical fields where the unique = True, and it's letting me.

The PK of my models is unset, aka the AutoIncrementing Integer (i think this may be part of the problem).

Here is my unique=True field.

```
url = models.URLField("The URL", unique=True)
```

Nothing else is notable about this model, no Foreign relationships, nothing. Just A unique field which must be enforced (but is not), and an auto incrementing PK.

For the sake of some search engines, the PK must remain an auto incrementing integer.

Here is the SQLall for the model:

```
BEGIN:
    CREATE TABLE `Model_model` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ....
```

Thank you.

Comment: have you specified the db_index ??

Comment: constraints are not handled the same way for all database vendors. are you using sqlite or mysql or postgres?

Comment: mysql for the database, I have NOT specified db index, but i don't think you need to, its default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping and recreating your database. The `unique` constraint will not be updated in database, if you add it after creating the database tables. If you don't want to lose your data, you need to add the property manually in the database.